# The code doesn't calculate or show any Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a noob of HTML5 & Jquery. I've built a piece of code to calculate Loan Amount based on Term & Interest. But it seems doesn't work on my own. The numbers aren't calculated automatically and stay at 0. I appreciate any helps. Thank you everyone.

This is the Script for pasting on Wordpress Site

```
    <script>
        function pmt(rate_per_period, number_of_payments, present_value, future_value, type){
                if(rate_per_period != 0.0){
                    // Interest rate exists
                    var q = Math.pow(1 + rate_per_period, number_of_payments);
                    return -(rate_per_period * (future_value + (q * present_value))) / ((-1 + q) * (1 + rate_per_period * (type)));

                } else if(number_of_payments != 0.0){
                    // No interest rate, but number of payments exists
                    return -(future_value + present_value) / number_of_payments;
                }
                return 0;
            }


        function calcLoanezi(){

            var interest;
            if ($( "#invoice" ).val() =< 5000) {interest = 0.12}
            else if ($( "#invoice" ).val() >= 5001 && $( "#invoice" ).val() <= 10000) {interest = 0.10}
            else if ($( "#invoice" ).val() >= 10001 && $( "#invoice" ).val() <= 20000) {interest = 0.08}
            else if ($( "#invoice" ).val() >= 20001 && $( "#invoice" ).val() <= 35000) {interest = 0.0725}
            else if ($( "#invoice" ).val() >= 35001 && $( "#invoice" ).val() <= 60000) {interest = 0.0695}              
            else if ($( "#invoice" ).val() >= 60001 && $( "#invoice" ).val() <= 100000) {interest = 0.0675}

            var months;             // Lifetime of loan (in years)
            if ($("#term").val() >=60) {interest = interest+0.01}                   
            present     = $( "#invoice" ).val(),        // Present value  of loan
            future      = 0,        // Future value of loan
            beginning   = 0;        // Calculated at start of each period
            brokerage   = present * 0.06;

            var payment = -pmt((interest / 12), months, (Number(brokerage) + Number(present)), future, beginning);

            var payment_2dp_exgst = payment.toFixed(2);
            var payment_2dp_gst = ((payment*1.1)-payment).toFixed(2);
            var payment_2dp_incgst = (Number(payment_2dp_exgst) + Number(payment_2dp_gst)).toFixed(2);


            $( "#monthlyex" ).val("$"+payment_2dp_exgst);
            $( "#monthlygst" ).val("$"+payment_2dp_gst);
            $( "#monthlyinc" ).val("$"+payment_2dp_incgst);

        }

        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#invoice" ).keyup(function(){
            calcLoanezi();
        });
        $("#term").on('change', function() {
            calcLoanezi();
        });
        });

    </script>
```

It doesn't show any results

Comment: Time to probably put your debugging tools to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below should work (technically, but not without HTML, or at least mockup input). I gave it a bit more structure, concerns are separated.

If you provide the HTML, then the JS code snippet can modified to work (right now, you won't see any results, as there's no HTML attached).

**But you seem to have problems with calculation parameters,** and I think these may be the root of your problematic results:

- you don't do anything if the value is negative, or above 100.000
- you declare **months**, but it has no value (and you use it in a calculation)
- **future** and **beginning** have a value of 0 (you define it), and these 0s are passed in the calculation,
- **present**, **future**, **beginning** and **brokerage** are global (they are not **var**, **const** or **let**)

With a more structured approach to the code, you can see these calculation problems.

```js
// calculate interest
function calcInterest(val) {
  const interest = 0

  // you don't need to specify the lower bount of the "else if"s, because you can be sure that it will hit only one of them
  if (0 <= val && val < 5000) {
    interest = 0.12
  } else if (val <= 10000) {
    interest = 0.10
  } else if (val <= 20000) {
    interest = 0.08
  } else if (val <= 35000) {
    interest = 0.0725
  } else if (val <= 60000) {
    interest = 0.0695
  } else if (val <= 60000) {
    interest = 0.0695
  } else if (val <= 100000) {
    interest = 0.0675
  } // you don't have a "default else", so if val is 100001+, or is a negative number, then interest will be 0

  return interest
}

function pmt(rate_per_period, number_of_payments, present_value, future_value, type) {
  if (rate_per_period != 0.0) {
    // Interest rate exists
    var q = Math.pow(1 + rate_per_period, number_of_payments);
    return -(rate_per_period * (future_value + (q * present_value))) / ((-1 + q) * (1 + rate_per_period * (type)));

  } else if (number_of_payments != 0.0) {
    // No interest rate, but number of payments exists
    return -(future_value + present_value) / number_of_payments;
  }
  return 0;
}

// this function gets a lot of parameters
// future and beginning are always 0
function calcPayments(interest, months, brokerage, present, future, beginning) {
  var payment = -pmt((interest / 12), months, (Number(brokerage) + Number(present)), future, beginning)

  var payment_2dp_exgst = payment.toFixed(2);
  var payment_2dp_gst = ((payment * 1.1) - payment).toFixed(2);
  var payment_2dp_incgst = (Number(payment_2dp_exgst) + Number(payment_2dp_gst)).toFixed(2);

  return {
    payment_2dp_exgst,
    payment_2dp_gst,
    payment_2dp_incgst
  }

}

// main function
function calcLoanezi(present, term) {
  const interest = 60 < term ? calcInterest(present) + 0.01 : calcInterest(present)

  let months,
    future = 0,
    beginning = 0,
    brokerage = present * 0.06

  return calcPayments(interest, months, brokerage, present, future, beginning)
}

// DOM manipulation
function appendToDOM() {
  const {
    payment_2dp_exgst,
    payment_2dp_gst,
    payment_2dp_incgst
  } = calcLoanezi(Number($("#invoice").val()), Number($("#term").val()))

  jQuery("#monthlyex").val("$" + payment_2dp_exgst);
  jQuery("#monthlygst").val("$" + payment_2dp_gst);
  jQuery("#monthlyinc").val("$" + payment_2dp_incgst);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#invoice").keyup(function() {
    appendToDOM();
  });
  $("#term").on('change', function() {
    appendToDOM();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```